# In angular 7, can you have multiple event emitters passed into one component?

Tags: angular7, eventemitter

In my signature component, I am trying to pass two event emitters, and eventually a 3rd event emitter into it.

When there is one event emitter, it works as expected, when i have two event emitters none of the expected behavior is happening.

In my parent component,

```
   <div>
    <app-signature 
      (checkSubmitFlagForFirstSubmitEvent)=
        "receiveCheckSubmitFlagForFirstSubmit($event)"
        (myEvent)="confirmation.getStudentQuestionsData()"
     ></app-signature>
   </div>

   <div class="tab-pane fade show" id="confirmation" role="tabpanel" aria- 
     labelledby="cada-form-confirmation-tab">
     <app-confirmation #confirmation></app-confirmation>
   </div>
```

Am I missing something obvious here?  For the (myEvent)="confirmation.getStudentQuestionsData()", when the user clicks a button on the signature component, it should call a function from the confirmation component.

In my signature component TS file:

```
@Output() myEvent = new EventEmitter();
function2() {
  this.myEvent.emit(null)
}
```

In my signature component HTML file, I have a modal that pops up, when they click OK on the modal button, it should call a function from my confirmation component:

```
    <button type="button" class="close text-light" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true" (click)="closeModal('submit-wait'); function2()">&times;</span>
    </button>
```

In my confirmation component TS file, I'm trying to call the function getStudentQuestionsData() when the user clicks on a button from the signature component.

I am also calling it onInit, i dont think thats the cause of the issue though. I need the data when the app loads, and then when the user clicks on a button from signature component, it should call getStudentQuestionsData() again to refresh the data on the confirmation component.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.getStudentQuestionsData();
}

getStudentQuestionsData() {
  'calling some API'
}
```

Comment: It is definitely possible to bind to multiple events from a component. Are you seeing any errors in console when you do this? Can you show the code in the component?

Comment: Hi @WesleyTrantham I've edited my original post to include more code

Answer (score 1):

Currently your click event is inside of the span inside of the button. While your span is clicked it must not be bubbling the event up.

If you bind to the click event directly on the button it should start working better for you.

```
<button type="button" class="close text-light" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" (click)="closeModal('submit-wait'); function2()">
  <span aria-hidden="true" >&times;</span>  
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help Wesley, it was actually working but we were having some issues with our database at the time i was testing, so the API calls were failing.  Just FYI, calling the function within a span tag still works as well!

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out! Strangely in my minimal reproduction locally I was able to reproduce the click not firing, which I wasn't expecting. Might have been something I overlooked.